# Firebase Admin SDK NodeJS -- "There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier." Error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Following the Firebase SDK docs on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link and getting the following error, which makes little sense as the function is triggered from the server environment using the authenticated admin.auth().

Might anyone know what is causing the issue?

```
Error from admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink : { Error: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:147:16)
    at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:186:16)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:1201:49
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'auth/user-not-found',
     message: 'There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.' },
  codePrefix: 'auth' }
```

The code is just this:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document("xxx/{docId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    let yyy = snap.data();
    let { uid, userData } = yyy;
    console.log("from sendEmailVerification, uid, userdata: ", userData);
    const actionCodeSettings = {
      url: `${emailConfirmationUrl}`,
      handleCodeInApp: false
    };
    return admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(userData.email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(async (link) => {
        console.log("uid from generateEmailVerificationLink and email: ", uid, userData.email)
        await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set({
          verificationLink: link,
          emailVerified: false
        }, { merge: true });
        return emailfunc.sendCustomVerificationEmail(userData.email, link);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error from admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink :", err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You read the user's email address from the database (Firestore). That user account, however, doesn't exist in Firebase Auth. It must also exist in Firebase Auth if you wish to use APIs like `getUser()` and `generateEmailVerificationLink()`. Having it only in Firestore is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is quite confusing. Of course, the user exists in Firebase Auth - it's an anon user there. That's the point of the sending verification link - to let the user confirm it so that their email can be added to their anon (no longer) account. I think the error is being wrongly generated. admin.auth() should be able to send an email to any user. If what you suggest is the case, where is the uid being passed? The function in the example doesn't even ask for it...

Comment: If generateEmailVerification is a wrong function for server-side authenticating a user's email, do you know which one to use instead? The use case is extremely simple and common - confirm someone's email (which is not on their anon account yet) and associate it with their account if confirmed.

Comment: That's not how it works. The email address should already be in the Firebase Auth [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html#email), before calling `generateEmailVerificationLink()`. When the user eventually verifies the email by following link, the [`UserRecord.emailVerified`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html#emailverified) field gets set to true. You can't use this API to generate verification links for arbitrary email addresses.

Comment: Ok, so how do we set a user record for an anon user that has just given his email address (which may or may not be his or correct)?

Comment: I think you should just implement this in the client app. First [set the user's email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address) and then [send the verification email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email). If you must perform the 2nd step server-side, just set the user's email, and update a Firestore document to trigger a cloud function.

Comment: Unfortunately, not sure if this can work as the link itself ("set the user's email address") says "Important: To set a user's email address, the user must have signed in recently." So this excludes an anon use case. Any thoughts?

When you say "just set the user's email, and update a Firestore document to trigger a cloud function" - that's exactly what the above code is supposed to do, so not sure what needs to change there...

Comment: I think if the user has anonymously signed in recently, that should be good enough to set the email address. You need to set the email address on `firebase.auth().currentUser` before triggering any functions.

Comment: What's a bit weird is that even though an email gets verified after setting the email address of an anon user and sending them an email verification link, even after the click on the link, the user still shows as anonymous. I wonder if that's correct behaviour as a user with a verified email shouldn't be seen as anonymous anymore. You can repro it easily by giving an email to an anon user and verifying it with a link. The user still shows isAnonymous as true...

Comment: You probably have to convert the anonymous user into an email/password user account: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account

Comment: What are the differences between the two types? I quite liked the passwordless [benefits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) so didn't want to make a user come up with a password...